# c# TextBoxFor helper not correctly binding on post

Tags: c#, razor, binding

Html.TextBoxFor is not correctly binding the property value to the corresponding ViewModel property on POST.

Using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyObject.UserName)` renders the name attribute as "MyObject.UserName".

If I remove "MyObject." from the name attribute in chrome dev tools, then the properties post as expected. But of course you can't really name the attribute as c# razor overrides it. Even using `new { @name = "UserName"}` or `new { name = "UserName"}` or change it with javascript
However, manually setting the name attribute does not seem like the correctly way to handle this.

The only thing I can come up with is that I'm posting the specific "MyObjectViewModel" instead of the "PageViewModel" I rendered the page with.
**Note:** that the MyObjectViewModel is a child of PageViewModel.

I do not want to post the entire PageViewModel. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I believe my problem was a scoping issue between the two ViewModels.

I made my partial view have a ViewModel of type "MyObject", then passed `Model.MyObject` into that partial.

Now my view has the correct scoping for the name attributes to render correctly on the DOM so the POST captures them.